# protocol-relative links in static html pages

Tags: javascript, html, protocols

Today it is common to use `//server.tld/js/script.js` instead of the protocol-specific `http://server.tld/js/script.js` in `script`-Tags etc.

But I want to serve a static html page without any webserver (i.e. no `http://localhost:8080`).

The problem is that the browser interprets the protocol-relative link as `file:///js/script.js` and I can't circumvent this because it dynamically loads from a external server.

In this specific case, the script is `http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js`and loads `//connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js` at runtime.
Including a `script`-Tag pointing to `http://connect.soundcloud.com/soundmanager2/soundmanager2.js` directly in the html page doesn't solve the problem because there are some other dependencies, too.

There is also no way to get a webserver running (e.g. `php -S localhost:8080`), because it's for a client who doesn't wish to install anything.

So how can I define in the html file that procotol-relative links should use `http://` or `https://` as protocol instead of `file://`?

**EDIT**: Maybe I explain this with an example
In my html page I have a script tag (where I can control the used protocol)

```
<script src='http://example.org/some.js'></script>
```

And the script adds another tag in the dom

```
<script src='//example.org/helper.js'></script>
```

If I just open the html file `file:///.../file.html` the  browser thinks it should prepend `file://` so the script `src`  becomes `file://example.org/helper.js` or similar.

And it is not possible to just loop through the script tags and prepend a `http://`, because the script (`http://example.org/some.js`) might use ajax.

**EDIT**:
I don't think there is a way to set the protocol for 3rd-party-scripts if they use protocol-relative urls, so I leave this question as a reminder for someone who might encounter the same behaviour while working with 3rd-party-scripts and static html pages.
Would be nice if there would be a preinstalled webserver in Windows like in Linux' Python.

Comment: What system is it? Most operating systems ship with one HTTP server system another, php -S is not only the only way. You can always do it manually by the way.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's Windows, so not even Python's SimpleHTTPServer is installed. And the client can't execute a webserver. But it seems that a webserver is the only option.

Comment: Or... you can use JavaScript to alter the URLs. You can detect the current protocol and adapt accordingly. See the google analytics tracking code - it does just that.

Comment: I don't have any control over the used URLs (http or file) because it's all 3rd party (soundcloud.com). They should detect the current protocol and adapt, but they use relative paths which is totally understandable for me. So I think there is no way to change this behaviour, even the `base`-tag doesn't help. So I leave this question as documentation for that limitation.

Comment: Any reason you can't run IIS?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum No, only that the html page is so small that it would be overkill. But I think that's the way I have to go, lets see what the client thinks about that. I will give a little Batch Script which handles everything and that should be ok. Thanks for your support!