# How to modify my script socket.io to https?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm newbie on socket.io, I want to use my app on my site that currently runs on HTTPS so actually I have my server:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(server),
fs = require('fs'),
io = require('socket.io')(http);

function server(req, res){
fs.readFile('index.html',(err, data)=>{
    if(err){
        res.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        return res.end('<h1>Error</h1>');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        return res.end(data,'utf-8');
    }
})
}

http.listen(3000);
console.log("Running server");

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
socket.emit("hello",{ message : 'Hello world'})

})
```

Client index.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>        
        'use strict'
        var io =  io(),
        d = document

        io.on('hello', function(data){
            console.log(data);
            d.querySelector("#hello").innerHTML = data.message;
        })
</script>
```

This runs good in HTTP but how can I modify it for HTTPS?

**EDIT:**

According to [node docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.2.6/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) I changed server script like this:

```
var http = require('https'),
fs = require('fs'),
io = require('socket.io')(http);

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('myprivkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('mycert.pem')
};

http.createServer(options, (req,res)=>{

fs.readFile('index.html',(err, data)=>{
    if(err){
        res.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        return res.end('<h1>Error</h1>');
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        return res.end(data,'utf-8');
    }
})
}).listen(3000);

console.log("Running server");

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
   socket.emit("hello",{ message : 'Hello world'})
})
```

I run server and shows no error but client doesn't work, if I run mysite.com:3000/myapp in the browser, console says: '**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**' and '**Uncaught TypeError: io is not a function**'.

And if I run mysite.com/myapp console says: '**GET www.mysite.com/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)**' and '**Uncaught TypeError: io is not a function**'.

I want this run when I enter mysite.com/myapp, "myapp" is the folder name where is located server script and client index.html

What else must be modified?

Comment: Took a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965985/protocol-relative-links-in-static-html-pages

Comment: Do you have public/private keys for your domain? You can follow [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener) on nodejs.org.

Comment: Yes, I have my key and cert, my website runs on HTTPS actually

Comment: Just start an https server instead of an http server and use that server with socket.io.  Use the `https` module, not the `http` module.

Answer (score 0):

There are two general ways to do what you are asking. Generally, in production environments, nodejs based servers are run with what is called a reverse proxy. This is basically nginx or another web server sitting in front and passing along network requests node needs to care about. Under this scenario, the reverse proxy usually handles the HTTPS side of things, and node only has to deal with http.

The other way to do it is to have node deal with the TLS security of https itself. To do this, you have to get an https certificate (letsencrypt is a good option here), and tell your server instance about it like so:

```
var http = require('http').createServer(server),
fs = require('fs');

// Add https certificate
var crypto = require('crypto');
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem').toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem').toString();
var credentials = crypto.createCredentials({key: privateKey, cert: certificate});

http.setSecure(credentials);

var io = require('socket.io')(http);

function server(req, res){
    fs.readFile('index.html',(err, data)=>{
        if(err){
            res.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            return res.end('<h1>Error</h1>');
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
            return res.end(data,'utf-8');
        }
    })
}

http.listen(3000);
console.log("Running server");

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    socket.emit("hello",{ message : 'Hello world'})
})
```

Comment: What's `http.setSecure()`? Why not use [`https.createServer()`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener)?

Comment: Thanks for answer, the first way is not my case, because this only worked when I typed url with http, and the second way doesn't work because it says crypto is deprecated and when I run server is shows:  (node) crypto.createCredentials is deprecated. Use tls.createSecureContext instead. http.setSecure(credentials);  TypeError: http.setSecure is not a function

Comment: @robertklep, I guess the documentation I found must be old. I'll try to update with more recent code.